# C-M-d not working on Emacs GUI OSX using Mac Command key as Meta

Tags: osx, prelude

I'm using Emacs GUI on OSX and I've remapped `Cmd` key to meta by adding the following to a `~/.emacs.d/personal/misc.el` file on prelude:

```
(setq mac-command-modifier 'meta)
```

Whereas `C-M-u` works as expected, `C-M-d`, when using `Cmd` as meta key, does nothing. If using alt key though, it works as expected.

What can I do to solve this? I've tried typing `C-h l` to see what's being typed but when I type `C-M-d`, nothing appears.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: This sounds like it might be a system level OSX keyboard shortcut that is overriding an Emacs one. I had a similar issue on Ubuntu getting `M-SPC` to work in Emacs. If you know how to change/disable the OSX binding for Ctrl + Command + d, that might do the trick.

Comment: @elethan, you are a legend!! Your clue lead to me to the answer, which is explained [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22785/how-do-i-disable-the-command-control-d-word-definition-keyboard-shortcut-in-os-x) :D

Comment: nice! Happy to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elethan's tip lead me to the answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22785/how-do-i-disable-the-command-control-d-word-definition-keyboard-shortcut-in-os-x), which essentially involves disabling system wide OSX Command-Control-D shortcut by calling:

```
defaults write com.apple.symbolichotkeys AppleSymbolicHotKeys -dict-add 70 '<dict><key>enabled</key><false/></dict>'
```

Comment: @elethan et al, I've sent a [PR](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/pull/630) to mathiasbynens's .osx dotfiles so that it gets disabled there and many Emacs users can benefit. Vote it up! :)